# alternative for facebook apis deprecation

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

While going through recent facebook API and platform product changes at :
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/04/facebook-api-platform-product-changes/

I see that there are few APIs like posts/ , comments/ etc. which are going to be deprecated. It is not mentioned anywhere when are they going to be removed completely and their alternative.

Does anyone have an idea about timeline and alternatives ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can see the timeframe for deprecations in the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes

The endpoints you mentioned (event/posts, event/comments) are removed already, as you can read just a few lines before they got mentioned: "Below are some immediate changes to these APIs."

There are no alternatives, or they would have mentioned it. Access to event feeds is just not possible anymore.